# MFP_PERSISTENT_DATA Truncate Issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Using MFP8, I have truncated MFP_PERSISTENT_DATA and MFP_TRANSIENT_DATA of more than 0.8 million records in live.

Currently, iOS users are facing issues and can see the below logs in server. How to rectify the same

ibm.mfp.server.registration.internal.RegistrationServiceImpl E **FWLSE4213E**: Client JWT authentication failed - **public keys do not match** com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.WebTokenException: Invalid signature

ibm.mfp.server.registration.internal.rest.RegistrationEndpoint E **FWLSE4225E**: Invalid update self registration request, client signature could not be verified com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.WebTokenException: **Invalid signature**

ibm.mfp.server.registration.internal.rest.RegistrationEndpoint E **FWLSE4224E**: Failed to process registration request.
com.ibm.mfp.server.core.shared.MFPRESTException: 400; headers=[]; body={ errorCode=**APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST** errorMsg=Application doesn't exist}

Comment: what is the level of MFP SDK you are using ? can you share the wireshark here ? does the mfp console still show your application ?

Comment: **APPLICATION_DOES_NOT_EXIST** issue is fixed by adding that version in MFP Console.

Currently, I have that **Invalid Signature** and **Public Keys do not match** issues only

Comment: Ok Clarify the level of MFP SDK you have

Comment: cordova-plugin-mfp in package.json is **^8.0.2017121811**
mfp:platformVersion in config.xml is **8.0.0.00-20171219-120008**

Comment: Ok, you need to either update the level of MFP Sdk to latest version say MFP8 starting 2018 Nov or later. If that is not possible you need to either uninstall or install the application or attempt to do setserverurl for the above error which will clear and do fresh registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, random deletion of entries from the MFP-PERSISTENT_DATA is not at all recommended thing to do.for any cleanup of tables, we would recommend you to do so via https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/12/27/purge-mfp-runtime-tables/. suggestions given your current scenario is

1) Starting Nov 2018 level of SDK, Intelligence is incorporated in to MFP SDK to take care of such accidental deletions by cleaning up client context and doing fresh registration. If the customer’s application has a client SDK level that takes care of auto registration , this issue would not appear and MFP SDK will recover from the above error scenario by cleaning up and doing fresh registration . As per information provided below, customer is in a  older level of SDK and the auto re registration feature requires an SDK level of Nov 2018 or later.

2) Is there a way to backup / restore data which you have truncated ? if you have taken backup / can you restore and follow proper instructions to clean up as updated in the blog above ?

3)Provided there is no way to restore / cannot upgrade their application to a newer level of SDK , options are to manually clear the application cache /uninstall and reinstall of the application which needs end user actions   to recover.

4) Another option  is to update your application to setServerURL() method upon this error, but this would again need update to application and careful planning to ensure it is added appropriately only to the exact error scenario in the application logic as it clears the client context completely

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/api-ref/wl-android-n-java-apidoc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/androidgap/api/WL.html#setServerUrl(java.net.URL)